# Did we lose our main chatroom?

Tags: support, chat

We have two economics chatroooms that were created for specific discussions, but we seem to have lost our main chatroom.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=created&host=economics.stackexchange.com

Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was [frozen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1559?m=24782025#24782025) because it hasn't been used for weeks, and there was another room that had been used more recently, which was kept open instead. In this particular case that wasn't a good automatic decision, so I have unfrozen the main room and frozen the other one instead.