# Main chat room is frozen again

Tags: support

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104557/economics

It happened [before](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/did-we-lose-our-main-chatroom).

FYI: What I wanted to post there is a link to https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72038/what-does-putin-russia-gain-from-only-accepting-payment-for-gas-in-rubles

Comment: It is unfrozen.